# Issue creating side-by-side slideshows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a site with 2 slideshows. I've tweaked and re-tweaked the JS and Jquery numerous times.  Sometimes one slideshow works perfectly and the other cycles between one picture, other times both work but are out of sync, or the fadeIn doesn't seem to be applied to the second slideshow, or in some variations one slideshow stays frozen on the initial image and just remains static. Anyway, I created a JS Fiddle (link at bottom) and apparently my code is at least free of typos.  JS is below, the rest is on the JS Fiddle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".slider #1").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".slider #1").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);


    var sc = $(".slider img").size();
    var count = 2;

    setInterval(function () {
        $(".slider #" + count).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".slider #" + count).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

        if (count === sc) {
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }, 3500);


    $(".sliderTwo #7").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".sliderTwo #7").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);


    var sc2 = 12;
    var count2 = 7;

    setInterval(function () {
        $(".sliderTwo #" + count2).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".sliderTwo #" + count2).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

        if (count2 === sc2) {
            count2 = 7;
        } else {
            count2++;
        }
    }, 3500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gg4PL/

Comment: Firstly, ids should start with a letter - not a number. Secondly, the setInterval is an approximate timer only. The browser places these events at the end of the priority queue so you will probably never going to get them to run in the manner that you are hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:- Never write id as numbers.
try with `$(window).load` because `document.ready` always work once the basic html generated, however, window.load work when all the resources loaded into html like images etc...
I've seen on js fiddle it's working fine. 
What I've done is closed all the `<img>` tags properly due to which html starts working.
Removed `document.ready` from code and set onload in the left panel of jsfiddle

Selected jquery 1.8.3 in the left panel

Comment: Thanks; I'm still trying to learn all this. Didn't know about $(window).load. I figured using integers as id would be a shortcut way to include them in the JS function.  Should I be organizing them into an array instead, or do you recommend some other way to get JS to cycle through the images?

Comment: The code you've written is working fine. Sometimes slideshow time span changes. But it occurs rarely. Due to fade in, delay and fade out timings. So try to inserts those in such way so that everything comes in sync. Issues are mostly related to html. Try to resolve those as I've said in answer. Js fiddle itself shows the error by highlighting in red. Like I've seen in <img> tag you haven't closed it. Due to this js fiddle shows error in the end by highlighting curly brackets. So resolve those and it will work!!!